# MVC 5 - jQuery - Displaying FileContentResult Without Downloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to display the results of a `FileContentResult` MVC Action in an `object` tag. I can easily display files that have a preview option; .txt, .pdf, .jpg, etc. The problem comes in when there are files that don't have a preview option. 
My problem isn't figuring out which type of files work, my problem is figuring out how to stop them from downloading (or trying to download).
I've tried making an ajax call to grab the file, which I can do, but I don't know how to display it after that. 
Any tips or ideas? This is the object I get back from the jquery call.
[image]

It's essentially just the mimetype, the name, and the byte array. Here's a snap of the object in MVC:
[image]
This doesn't seem like it should be as hard as it seems. Am I just missing something obvious? 
 Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I realized what I could do in order to get around this problem, I won't submit this as the answer in case other people actually do have ideas on how to work around this. 
I think my solution is pretty self-explanatory, but I'll go into a little detail.

```
public ActionResult GetFile()
    {
        HBSFile file = new Common.Business.FileIO.FileIO(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images"), "testdoc.docx").Read();
        if (file.CanBePreviewed)
        {
            return File(file.Stream, file.ContentType);//, file.FileName + "." + file.Extension);
        }
        return null;
        //return Json(new Test(File(file.Stream, file.ContentType, file.FileName + "." + file.Extension), file.CanBePreviewed), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

The HBSFile object is simply the properties of the file. `file.Stream` is a byte array. 
 To get around my problem, I simply check to see if the file can be previewed or not. If it can be, I'll return a `FileContentResult`.